# Will GAMS optimize the default parameters of Solver?

Tags: solver, gams-math, coin-or-cbc

I have a MILP problem. I use CBC solver to solve it. If I call CBC through GAMS, the computation time will be short. But when I solve it directly using CBC.exe, it takes too much time. In both cases, I use the default value of the parameters. Is it GAMS that optimizes the parameters of CBC? Thank you to tell me the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAMS does not optimize the solver parameters explicitly. Though, in some cases it might set its own defaults. Also, is it possible, that your two formulations of the model are a little different?

Comment: I see why. The two CBC solver's versions are different. CBC in GAMS is lower version, but it solves my problem faster. That's interesting. Thank you for answering my question.@Lutz